# On sums of cubes of four integer valued polynomials

Tags: nt.number-theory, polynomials

Suppose $\alpha_i(x)$ for $i=1,2,3,4$ are polynomials with integer coefficients, and $P$ and $Q$ are integers such that for every $x$ we have

$$\sum_{1\leq i\leq 4} \alpha_i^3(x)=Px+Q \tag{1}$$

It is clear that in any such identity $3|P$; by differentiation. Furthermore, if we let $x=\omega$ where $\omega\neq 1$ is a cube root of unity, and compare the imaginary portions of each side of (1), we deduce that $2|P$ as well.

Suppose that instead of considering polynomials with integer coefficients, we consider the larger class of polynomials $\alpha_i(x)$ with rational coefficients that are integral valued on the integers. It is no longer the case that we must have $2|P$; for example
$$\left(\frac{3n(n-1)}{2}-n-13\right)^3+\left(\frac{-3n(n-1)}{2}+5n+5\right)^3+(3n^2-5n-9)^3+(-3n^2+4n+14)^3=357n-57$$

In any such identity, however, it appears that we still require $3|P$, although differentiation no longer shows this since the coefficients are no longer integral. The question is, how does one prove this is true in general, if it is true?

I can prove this is true if the maximum degree of the $\alpha_i(x)$ is $\leq 27$, but the proof is rather complicated. Below I give an elementary argument that proves this is true if the maximum degree of the $\alpha_i(x)$ is $\leq 9$.

Suppose the maximum degree of the four polynomials is $\leq 9$. Since the binomial coefficients form a basis for the class of integer valued polynomials with rational coefficients, we may write

$$\alpha_i(x)=a_{9,i}\binom{x}{9}+a_{8,i}\binom{x}{8}+\cdots+a_{1,i}x+a_{0,i}$$

where the $a_{j,i}$ are integers for each $i=1,2,3,4$ and $0\leq j\leq 9$.
We require $\sum_{1\leq i\leq 4}\alpha_i^3(x)=Px+Q$ for every $x$, where $P$ and $Q$ are integers.

Suppose $3\nmid P$. Set $x=u+t$ for some fixed integer $t$. Since $3\nmid P$, we may choose $t$ so that $Pt+Q\equiv 4\mod 9$; so we do so. Since translation of an integer valued polynomial by an integer is still an integer valued polynomial, we then have

$$\alpha_i(x)=\alpha_i(u+t)=\beta_i(u)=b_{9,i}\binom{u}{9}+b_{8,i}\binom{u}{8}+\cdots+b_{1,i}u+b_{0,i}$$

where the $b_{j,i}$ are integers. Let $Q_0=Pt+Q$. Then

$$\sum_{1\leq i\leq 4}\alpha^3_i(x)=Px+Q\Rightarrow \sum_{1\leq i\leq 4} \beta^3_i(u)=Pu+Q_0\tag{2}$$

where $Q_0\equiv 4\mod 9$.

Setting $u=0$ in (2) we have $\sum_{1\leq i\leq 4} b^3_{0,i}=Q_0\equiv 4\mod 9$ from whence $b_{0,i}\equiv 1\mod 3$ for each $i$.

Setting $u=9$ in (2) we deduce $\sum_{1\leq i\leq 4}(b_{9,i}+b_{0,i})^3\equiv 4\mod 9\Rightarrow b_{9,i}+b_{0,i}\equiv 1\mod 3\Rightarrow b_{9,i}\equiv 0\mod 3$ for each $i$.

Set $b_{9,i}=3\delta_{9,i}$. Then setting $u=9$ in (2) and working modulo 27 we deduce

$$\sum_{1\leq i\leq 4} (b^3_{0,i}+9b^2_{0,i}(b_{3,i}+b_{6,i}+\delta_{9,i}))\equiv 9P+Q_0\mod 27$$

Since, comparing coefficients in (2), we have $\sum_{1\leq i\leq 4} b^3_{0,i}=Q_0$, we have

$$\sum_{1\leq i\leq 4} 9b^2_{0,i}(b_{3,i}+b_{6,i}+\delta_{9,i})\equiv 9P\mod 27$$

so that $\sum_{1\leq i\leq 4} b^2_{0,i}(b_{3,i}+b_{6,i}+\delta_{9,i})\equiv P\mod 3$.

Noting that (2) implies $\sum_{1\leq i\leq 4} \beta_i(u)\equiv Pu+Q_0 \mod 3$ for each integer $u$, it is easy to deduce by taking $u=0,1,2,...,9$ that

$$\sum b_{9,i}\equiv\sum b_{8,i}\equiv \cdots\equiv \sum b_{2,i}\equiv 0\mod 3$$

so in particular $\sum b_{3,i}\equiv\sum b_{6,i}\equiv 0\mod 3$. Additionally since $b_{0,i}\equiv 1\mod 3$

$$\sum_{1\leq i\leq 4} b^2_{0,i}(b_{3,i}+b_{6,i}+\delta_{9,i})\equiv P\mod 3 \Longrightarrow \sum_{1\leq i\leq 4} \delta_{9,i}\equiv P\mod 3$$

Comparing coefficients of $u^9$ in (2) we have $0=\sum b^3_{9,i}=\sum  27 \delta^3_{9,i}$ so $0=\sum\delta^3_{9,i}\equiv \sum \delta_{9,i}\mod 3$. Hence $3|P$.

I do not see how to extend the argument given above in a way that generalizes to all degrees. I am hoping that perhaps someone sees how to do this, or that someone sees how to prove this perhaps without resorting to the binomial coefficient basis. As stated, I do know it is true if the maximum of the degrees of the polynomials is $\leq 27$ (but the proof is by no means straightforward), so I sense it is true in general. Any ideas are appreciated, and as a new poster, I apologize if I said too much here, but it did say to include any supporting work so I hope I did the right thing. I apologize in advance if I did not. Thank you to anyone who considers my question.

Comment: Nice proof! I hope you don't mind my edits.

Comment: Not at all; looks much better.